# Inspect Mode nor Design Mode not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, browser-link

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Web Essentials 2015 (v0.5.193).

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, hosted in IIS, running locally on my PC. Although my Visual Studio browser link menu picks up that a browser is navigating to the site (e.g. Chrome), when I click on the 'Inspect' option on the little Web Essentials menu that appears on a web apge, the page goes dark and the mouse cursor changes to a cross, but I can't actually pick any element.

When I create a new, simple, ASP.NET MVC 5 web application (not hosted in IIS, but running in IIS Express) and try the 'Inspect' option, this time I get the  dark overlay, cross cursors and can click on an element and be shown which view file it lives in.

Some I'm stuck on why my IIS hosted web app does not have the inspect, or design, modes working.

UPDATE:

So, inspect has now just started working on the IIS hosted site??? Weird. I've no idea why.

Comment: I have this same issue.. only happens when I change to Local IIS :/ hmm

Comment: I haven't used this feature for so long, I actually forgot about this question.